# Установить системное время Windows в 1547 год

Tags: windows-10

Windows 10, требуется установить системное время в 1547 год (время, месяц и день месяца не важны).

В стандартном диалоге установки даты/времени диапазон выбора года ограничен (1987-2047).

Comment: Вы там машину времени испытываете что ли? :)

Comment: @Visman исключительно для тестирования софта )

Comment: Что то мне подсказывает, что это нельзя сделать. Windows время синхронизирует с счетчиком в CMOS, а он в секундах с 1.01.1970

Comment: А вот Win7 не дает опуститься ниже 1980 года.

Comment: @Visman то же не понял, по какому критерию нижняя граница, ведь windows 10 не было еще в 1987.

Comment: У них разница в выходе 6 лет. разница в ограничениях 7. думаю берут -20 лет с некими округлениями. Ну или с потолка :)

Comment: если Вам это удастся то боюсь Ваш компьютер превратится в счеты.

Answer (score 2):

Я хотел посоветовать Вам перейти на [исламский календарь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C), но у них еще не наступил 1547 год, возможно стоит поискать более подходящий вариант или, если нет ограничений на использование будущего, должно подойти. Как заметил @Visman, если это машина времени, поделитесь с общественностью! :)

Answer (score 2):

В винде эпоха начинается с 1601 года, поэтому системное время в 1547 вы выставить не сможете никак.

Более поздние даты вы можете попробовать выставить через вызов функции [SetSystemTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms724942(v=vs.85).aspx)